# How to troubleshoot and resolve a Typo3 503 Error?

Tags: typo3, http-status-code-503

I'm facing an error in Typo3 where I want a existing project on a different machine.

When installing everything like composer, WAMP and the typo3 installation I get a 503 error on the webpage.

I use path:
http://localhost/Project/public/typo3/login?redirect=site_configuration
which causes a 503 error.

the path:
http://localhost/Project/public/

Gives me a default PHP landing page.

I've managed to change the database credentials to the ones I use which are found in the `LocalConfiguration.php`. If that might be the problem.

Does anyone know what this message might cause and how i can fix this so my application will be runnable?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find HTTP-error reasons in your WAMP Apache Error Log. Also you may want to enable display_errors=1 in your php.ini.

However - I recommend not to use TYPO3 with composer on a localhost/.../public/... directory scope, that will create trouble sooner or later due to asset URIs.

Instead, you should try to create your own TYPO3 host (like "typo3.localhost"). Before you proceed with that using WAMP and setup distinc DocumentRoots and hostnames, it is much easier to use DDEV.

Please check out https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/Installation/TutorialDdev.html for detailed instructions on how to locally use TYPO3 with ddev. It will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: I have to do it with composer because the existing project is already using that I just have to move it to my local computer.

I got a lot of files like index.php and such. do I have to move them in public? could the misplacing of that be the case it is not showing anything?

Comment: You still use composer in ddev!